# Unable to get a Stripe Checkout session object

Tags: stripe-payments

Stripe.Net v34.16.0 bounces my code on the creation of the checkout session object responding with:

StripeException: No such plan: plan_myPlanId; a similar object exists in live mode, but a test mode key was used to make this request.

I do not see a means in the Stripe Dashboard to designate a given plan as a test plan .I also do not see
anything resembling a mode property.. my code

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
            {

                //var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
                //user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

                StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = "sk_test_mytestkey"; 


                var options = new Stripe.Checkout.SessionCreateOptions
                {               
                    PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string> {
                        "card",
                    },
                    SubscriptionData = new Stripe.Checkout.SessionSubscriptionDataOptions
                    {
                        Items = new List<SessionSubscriptionDataItemOptions> {
                            new SessionSubscriptionDataItemOptions {
                                Plan = "plan_myplanid",
                            },
                        },
                    },
    //to do
                    SuccessUrl = "localhost://home",
                    CancelUrl = "localhost://home",
                    //CancelUrl = "https://example.com/cancel",
                };

                var service = new Stripe.Checkout.SessionService();

                Stripe.Checkout.Session session = service.Create(options); //error out here           

                StripeCheckoutSessionId stripeCheckoutSessionId = new StripeCheckoutSessionId();
                stripeCheckoutSessionId.StripeSessionID = session.Id;

                return View(stripeCheckoutSessionId);

            }
```

I am referring to Stripe sample code in the .Net tab here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/subscriptions/starting

I appreciate your guidance in correcting my errors.

Comment: You wouldn't designate a specific plan as a test plan; within the stripe dashboard there is a switch you can set for live mode vs test mode. When in test mode, it uses a development API key, and any data fetched or posted with the development API key exists in a sandbox separate from the production data. So it looks like your code is using the development API key to interact with test data (which makes sense since you are using localhost urls) but is referencing a plan that *doesn't* exist in your test data, and Stripe tries to be helpful letting you know that plan *does* exist in production

Comment: Where is that switch. I am unable to locate it or any documentation reference to it. Thank you.

Comment: I don't have access to my dashboard atm to find it. But I just want to clarify, setting the switch does not change how your API requests to Stripe are handled: It just changes what shows up in the Stripe Dashboard.

The main docs on the Dashboard mention it: https://stripe.com/docs/dashboard